# What is the correct configuration for 3-wire RTDs connected to an ADAM 6015 module?

Tags: rtd

I have connected four RTDs by wire (via a 12 pin cable). The common wires of all four RTDs go through only two of the wires in the cable. After soldering those wires together and connecting them to one of the ADAM 6015 COM ports, I have tried two different configurations; using jumper wires between the RTD- port on the module and the adjacent com port, and not using jumper wires--only having the commons connected through the soldered wires and one of the ADAM com ports.

It seems like the com ports on the ADAM module are connected internally because I get low/no resistance when measured with a multimeter and I still get temp readings without using additional jumper wires. However, my temp readings with jumper wires is about 2-3 degrees Celsius higher than the readings without the jumpers. This makes me think there is additional resistance from the jumper wires. Which way yields accurate readings?

I have looked at the diagrams in the manual for the ADAM 6015 and they are ambiguous to me, seeming to just indicate that the common should be connected to the RTD- at some point, not necessarily directly at the RTD- and Com ports.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE, Timothy, but you need to provide datasheet links for devices mentioned in your questions. Make it easy for us!

Answer (score 0):

The user manual shows:
[image]

On the RTD the two wires that go to COM and RTD0- should be the same color, and their order of connection doesn't matter, as you can see from the drawing, they are in parallel.

This is a sort of Kelvin connection, like the 4 wire type, but less expensive and still good enough for most RTD resolution.

Answer (score 0):

A 3-wire RTD will have one outgoing and two incoming signals. Physically this looks like 3 wires where two are the same colour and the other is different.

The odd coloured wire is your RTD+.

The similarly coloured wires are you RTD-/COM.

The reason for the two wires coming back from the RTD is that most RTD modules will compensate for wire resistance in order to improve the accuracy of the reading. This makes the RTD accurate regardless of whether it is 1, 10, or 100 feet away (generally, and depending on RTD).

A jumper between COM and RTD- will skew this reading. No wire to COM will essentially give you a 2-wire RTD and you can calibrate the reading yourself. The proper way to connect this would be to bring all three wires back from the original RTD. That should be possible with a 12-wire cable.